# Using MinGW's GCC inline assembly to load IDT structure fails

Tags: c, gcc, x86, mingw, inline-assembly

In an attempt to get the Interrupt Descriptor Table's data using the following code:

```
/* SIDT returns IDT in following format */
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short IDTLimit;
    unsigned short LowIDTBase;
    unsigned short HighIDTBase

} s_idt_info;
#pragma pack()

.
.
.

    s_idt_info idt_info;        // returned by sidt
    s_idt_entry *idt_entries;   // obtained from idt_info
    unsigned long count;

    // load idt_info
    __asm ("sidt idt_info");
```

I get the following error:

```
||=== Build: Release in driver2 (compiler: gnu_64) ===|
obj\Release\driver.o:driver.c|| undefined reference to `idt_info'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Using MinGW-64bit's g++ compiler

Comment: gcc is not an "inline assembler" and that's not related to mingw!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Olaf : I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, since this is really the issue of GCC basic inline assembly only having visibility of global variables. In this case `idt_info` is likely local to the function the code was in (that is a bit of a guess since the function isn't shown in the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC doesn't support local variables (inside a function) within inline assembly unlike MSVC. If the variable `idt_info` were made global then it should be visible to the inline assembly, however the [*GCC* documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate) discourages this:

> **Accessing data from C programs without using input/output operands** (such as by using global symbols directly from the assembler template) **may not work as expected**. Similarly, calling functions directly from an assembler template requires a detailed understanding of the target assembler and ABI.
>
> **Since GCC does not parse the assembler template, it has no visibility of any symbols it references**. This may result in GCC discarding those symbols as unreferenced unless they are also listed as input, output, or goto operands.

What you want to do is use a [*GCC* extended assembler template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) and use an output constraint to allow *GCC* to pass in the address of `idt_info` that will be updated by *SIDT*. Something like this should work:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("sidt %[idtptr]" : [idtptr]"=m"(idt_info));
```

The `=` denotes the constraint will be used for output, `m` forces *GCC* to pass a memory operand. [*SIDT*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SIDT.html) requires a memory operand and not a register. `%[idtptr]` is the name given to the parameter, and *GCC* will replace it with the actual memory reference.